# c# and calendar: how to select a day (raise the SelectedDaysChanged event)

Tags: c#, calendar

I am using .NEt 4.0 (C#) and I have a calendar control. I have the SelecteddaysChanged event, but when I do click in one day in the calendar, the event is not rised, so I think that really the property SelectedDays has not changed.

I have the property sigle date selection mode of the calendar, but I try other options but the event does not rise.

I want that when the user select a day, with the mouse, or with the keyboard, rise the event SelectedDaysChanged because I need to do a query to the database.

Comment: yes, is winForm. WPF. Also I am using MVVM pattern.

Comment: Then you should tag WPF in here

Comment: Well, the problem was that in the binding of the command I wrote wrong the property command in the view model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem was that in the binding of the command I wrote wrong the property command in the view model.

Thanks.